# Select element in a multidimension list containing one element

Tags: list-manipulation

Imagine that I have a list like:

```
list={{{{1}}}}
```

To access the number 1, I could do list[[1]][[1]][[1]][[1]]

Of course it is very ugly but this is how I would do it given my knowledge.

What is the cleanest way to access the number in such list ? Can I go "from the bottom to the up" ?

Comment: May be use `list//Flatten` or `Level[list, -1]`

Answer (score 1):

First: You can put a list of indices into a single pair of `[[...]]` to access elements of nested lists (which already improves readability a lot):

```
list = {{{{1, 2}}}}
(* {{{{1, 2}}}} *)

list[[1]][[1]][[1]][[1]]
(* 1 *)

list[[1, 1, 1, 1]]
(* 1 *)
```

Going from the bottom up is generally more difficult: For the case of a (nested) list of integers (or other atomic expressions, see [`AtomQ`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/AtomQ.html)), you can take a look at [`Level`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Level.html) to get the deepest parts:

```
Level[list, {-1}]
(* {1, 2} *)

Level[list, {-1}][[1]]
(* 1 *)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try also this:

```
f[x_, a_] := x[[a]];   

 Fold[f, list, Table[1, Depth[list] - 1]]

(* 1 *)
```

Have fun!

Answer (score 1):

If you want the position specification required to `Extract` a particular element, use `Position`.

```
pos = Position[list, 1]
(* {{1, 1, 1, 1}} *)

Extract[list, pos]
(* {1} *}
```